# How do I convert this list into string

Tags: python, arrays, string, function, encryption

I made code for taking a string and converting it into a cipher, it just reverses the given string and add respective index number  to each of the alphabetical order number(eg;"adf"=653, f=6+0,d=4+1,a=1+2) . I want the output as string as well.

```
def code(str):
     str = str.lower()
     rev_str = str[::-1]
     list = []

     for i in range(len(str)):
         list.append(ord(rev_str[i]) - 96)

     for i in range(len(str)):
          list[i] = list[i] + i
          print(list[i],end="")

string = input("Enter the string: ")
code(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
def code(str):
     str = str.lower()
     rev_str = str[::-1]
     list = []

     for i in range(len(str)):    
         list.append(ord(rev_str[i]) - 96)

     for i in range(len(str)):   
          list[i] = list[i] + i

     output = ''
     print(output.join(list))           # To get the output as string.

string = input("Enter the string: ")
code(string)
```

Comment: i'm sorry that was my mistake on the qstion,the loop should start from the 0 and add consecutive number not 1.

Comment: print(output.join(list))  # To get the output as string.
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: canu give me your email address

Answer (score 0):

Updated version

```
def code(str):
     str = str.lower()
     rev_str = str[::-1]
     list = []
     res = ""

     for i in range(len(str)):
         list.append(ord(rev_str[i]) - 96)

     for i in range(len(str)):
          res = res + chr(list[i] + i)

     return res

string = input("Enter the string: ")

print (code(string))
```

Comment: i tried this and it doesent seems to work, i think the 'join' used only for strings..i got the following error  TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found

Comment: Hello. I have updated my solution. doing operation on list[i] "transforms" the values into int which cannot be directly assigned back to a string. `chr(i)`ensure i is treated back as a char and not an int